# Path of jquery-ui.css in Yii

Tags: yii

I am using Yii framwork and whenever i open the page,it loads jquery-ui.css in assets.I want to change that css and apply my css.How can i change that css. Or from where this file comes.What is the path of jquery-ui.css in framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`scriptMap`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#scriptMap-detail) feature of the `clientScript` component. It allows you to override any `*.js` or `*.css` file from the core (or other) packages. All you need is to configure it in your `main.php`.

```
'components' => array(
    'clientScript' => array(
        'scriptMap' => array(
            'jquery-ui.css' => '/css/my-own-jquery-ui.css',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Really nice info there! If I could vote up twice, this would be the time. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

The file you are looking for can be found here:

```
framework/web/js/source/jui/css/base/jquery-ui.css
```

By the way, changing of core files is not recommended. It will be better to create your own css files and rewrite some rules there.

Comment: This can't be stressed enough: Do **never** change any framework file! You will curse yourself whenever you want to upgrade the framework to a new version. Instead copy the file to your own `/css` directory and modify it there. Then use one of the other described techniques to use it with your widget.